# Simplifying to Linear Differential Operator?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, partial-derivative

Days ago and I'm trying to understand this equation

please help

If the linear  differential operator  $$C= C_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+C_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+C_0$$

and $\phi(x,y)$ is any solution of $C[\phi(x,y)]=0$
then $$\phi^{-1}C\phi = C_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+C_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

If we let $ E=\phi^{-1}C\phi $, then $C=\phi E \phi^{-1} $

By substituting for the operator $C$ and simplifying , we get

$$e^{c C}f(x,y)=e^{c\phi E \phi^{-1}}f(x,y)= \phi (x,y) e^{cE}[\phi^{-1}(x,y)f(x,y)]$$

> Is this statement is true, and why?
>
> $e^{c\phi E \phi^{-1}}f(x,y)= \phi (x,y) e^{cE}[\phi^{-1}(x,y)f(x,y)]$

Thanks for participating

> Update:[image]

Comment: Did you dig up that formula in a book of did you make it up yourself?

Comment: The first formula is true.
see my update

Comment: I'm sorry for the weak language, because I'm not English. please,where is the scientific errors in this page

Comment: Please note that I have deleted my first answer and formulated another one that is hopefully more helpful. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $\;\phi^{-1} = 1/\phi\;$ and that the product operator (i.e function) happens to be at the same time a solution. Then everything on that page seems indeed to be correct and:
$$
e^{c\phi E \phi^{-1}}f(x,y)= \left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\phi\, cE \,\phi^{-1}\right)^n / n! \right] f(x,y)
$$
Where:
$$
\left(\phi\,cE\,\phi^{-1}\right)^n = \left(\phi\,cE\,\phi^{-1}\right)\left(\phi \,cE\,\phi^{-1}\right)\left(\phi\,cE\,\phi^{-1}\right)\cdots =\\ \phi\,cE\cdot 1/\phi\ \cdot\phi\,cE\cdot 1/\phi \cdot \phi\,cE\cdot 1/\phi\cdots = \phi\left(cE\right)^n\phi^{-1}
$$
Because $\,1/\phi\cdot \phi = 1$ . Hence the formula follows:
$$
e^{c\phi E \phi^{-1}}f(x,y)= \left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi\left(cE\right)^n \,\phi^{-1}/n! \right]f(x,y) = \phi \left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(cE\right)^n /n! \right] \phi^{-1}  f(x,y) \\ = \phi (x,y) e^{cE}[\phi^{-1}(x,y)f(x,y)]
$$

Comment: I am so sorry for being late but there is no electricity in Gaza Strip days ago